# cannot define constant in class php

Tags: php

I am learning php now using code academy website but some is not explained properly.

These are the conditions:

1. Create a class called `Cat`.
2. Add two public properties to this class: `$isAlive` ought to store the value `true` and `$numLegs` should contain the value 4.
3. Add a public `$name` property, which gets its value via the `__construct()` or.
4. Add a public method called `meow()`, which returns "Meow meow".
5. Create an instance of the `Cat` class, which has the `$name` "CodeCat".
6. Call the `meow()` method on this Cat and echo the result.

This is the code created :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title> Challenge Time! </title>
      <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        <?php
          // Your code here
          class Cat {
             public $isAlive = true;
             public $numLegs = 4;
             public $name ;

              public function __construct() {
                  $cat->name = $name;;
                  }
              public function meow(){
                  return "Meow meow";
                  }
              }


              $cat = new Cat(true ,4 , CodeCat);
              echo $cat->meow();
        ?>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to use **HTML** code to write any **PHP** script

Comment: Second, your Cat class constructor takes no input arguments but when creating instance of class you're passing three arguments.

Comment: Welcome.
http://phpio.net/s/6ue
BTW, I think you should learn Object-Oriented Programming concepts.

Comment: thx guys, i found some literature now on Object-Oriented Programming concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have a constructor with no parameters, so `$name` will be undefined. And when you want to create a new object `Cat` you call it with 3 params, but you don't have a constructor like that.

What you want is to have a constructor with 1 param `$name` and call it with that param like this:

```
<?php
      // Your code here
      class Cat {
         public $isAlive = true;
         public $numLegs = 4;
         public $name ;

         public function __construct($name) {
              $this->name = $name;
         }
         public function meow(){
              return $this->name;
         }
      }


      $cat = new Cat('CodeCat');  //Like this you will set the name of the cat to CodeCat
      echo $cat->meow();  //This will echo CodeCat
?>
```

Comment: in constructor, instead of `$cat->name = $name;` it should be `$this->name = $name;`

Comment: Creating default object from empty value (line 17)Meow meow

Comment: @VitalikJimbei I updated my answer so when you call `meow` will return the cat name. I simply change the hardcoded string with `$this->name`

Comment: @Haridarshan how do i call function meow meow with the new inputted cats name ?

Comment: @VitalikJimbei try `echo $cat->name;`

Comment: @DanielDudas can i get your skype or smth if i have some more questions through the process of learning ? :)

Answer (score 2):

There's three mistakes:

1. __constructor without parameters
2. Using undefined variable `$cat` inside constructor instead of
   `$this`
3. `CodeCat` should be string `'CodeCat'`

Working code should look something like this:

```
<?php
          // Your code here
          class Cat {
             public $isAlive = true;
             public $numLegs = 4;
             public $name ;

              public function __construct($isAlive,$numLegs,$name) {
                  $this->name = $name;
                  $this->isAlive = $isAlive;
                  $this->numLegs = $numLegs;
                  }
              public function meow(){
                  return "Meow meow";
                  }
              }


              $cat = new Cat(true ,4 , 'CodeCat');
              echo $cat->meow();
        ?>
```

Comment: When initializing, you should make 'CodeCat' a string, or he will keep the same error.